# Getting Error value when I try to send value from JavaScript to PHP with ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I use `if (isset($_POST['category_drop'])) {...}` to check for the post condition in PHP.

Kindly provide me a solution.

```
$('.category_filter .dropdown-menu li a ').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var category = $(this).text();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'page_author.php',
        data: {
            category_drop: category
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // do something;
            alert(category);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting ? Or you're getting blank value?

Comment: @AlokPatel Yeah I make an echo statement like this ..if (isset($_POST['category_drop'])) {
         echo "done";
        } ... But I never get it

Comment: change `alert(category);` to `alert(data);` your response

Comment: Did you try to debug the value of category in javascript? Is it really set? Is the PHP code you showed the whole script? If not did you try using this simple version for your test?

Comment: @DavidJawphan I tried it before , but it displays the html scripts in the alert box.

Comment: @AlexanderKludt No this is not the complete PHP code , its just an intermediate process where the else part will be having the SQL queries

Comment: Would you want output to only `done` without html elements ?

Comment: @DavidJawphan This is just for testing purpose .. If I use if (!isset($_POST['category_drop'])) { echo "done"; } it displays me "done"

Comment: "page_author.php" is not getting reloaded with that POST value, because of that my webpage remains the same with only the alert statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var params = {'category_drop':category};

$.post('page_author.php', params, function(data) {
    //do stuff
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Why ? How it is different from what OP has shared ?

Comment: I'm not too sure about this, but i found something like this online. Maybe you can try change the data portion of your code to data: "category_drop=" + category;

Comment: hmm.. one more thing you can try. Keep ur code the same as before but add another parameter dataType: "JSON",

Answer (score 0):

OK, main problem was in your event setting. Check these codes:

**page_author.php (v1.0)**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['category_drop'])) echo $_POST['category_drop']; 
else echo 'Nothing!';
?>
```

**index.html (v1.0)**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(function(){// <---------------- document.ready event
        $('.category_filter .dropdown-menu li a').on('click', function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            var category = $(this).text();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'page_author.php',
                data: {
                    category_drop: category
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(category); // <----- using `data` is correct but using category has no problem, *I changed alert() to console.log()*
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="category_filter">
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    Click Me :)
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I created the click event inside document.ready and everything works now.
Just another thing, that you have to send enough code that people can help you. I added some html and other codes to test the code.

and *I used console.log() instead of alert()*, alert() is good, but console.log() is more pro. and you can see result in console's log, for example in Console of Firebug or something else.

**UPDATE - 21/SEP/2016** 
*[cause: questioner needs to change html face after success ajax]*

You want to show the result in your page, just do this:

**page_author.php (v1.1)**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['category_drop'])) echo $_POST['category_drop']; 
// else echo 'Nothing!'; // <-------- REMOVE THIS
?>
```

**index.html (v1.1)**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(function(){// <---------------- document.ready event
        $('.category_filter .dropdown-menu li a').on('click', function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            var category = $(this).text();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'page_author.php',
                data: {
                    category_drop: category
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#outdiv").html($("#outdiv").html()+"<b>This is the result from AJAX: </b> "+data+"<br/>"); // <------ This will change output div inner html after success ajax
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="category_filter">
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    Click Me :)
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="outdiv"></div><!------------ Result will show here -->
```

Just copy above code.

Comment: I am getting the value populated in console, but I need the page to be updated with the AJAX post value.

Comment: it is easy @Praveenkumar, you have to use an element like DIV in your HTML and use it for show output. **HTML:** `<div id="outdiv"></div>` **JS CODE** `$("#outdiv").html(data); //instead of console.log('....')`

Comment: in this sample `data` is just string, but you can work on it and make it more advanced, like sending arrays for multivalue data. I just answered to your request of solution and I don't know how you want to use this, but the answer is complete for whole purposes.

Comment: I tried using the exact way as you mentioned ,but I ended up with the error stating "Permission denied to access property **apply** " in firebug once the AJAX method is called.

Comment: @Praveenkumar check the update and just copy the code.

Comment: @Praveenkumar, didn't you found your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your supportive answers, Finally I got the output by the below method

```
$('.category_filter .dropdown-menu li a').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var category = $(this).text();
    console.log(category);
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "post",
        url: 'category_drop.php',
        data: {
            category_drop: category
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            $('#ajax_section').html(response);
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the difference with my 2 weeks ago answer?! look at my v1.1 dude that I posted 2 weeks ago.